# Doctrine and 'select * from only {{table}}' - Is it possible to avoid table inheritance without native querying?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity which uses a table called `software`. In the UI of the app I'm developing, all of the entries in `software` are useful to users in lists or dropdowns in forms. Unfortunately, the database automatically inherits another table called `software_dynamic` when selecting from `software`.

This makes it so the UI has approximately 15,000 software entries it doesn't need when using the entity in the Symfony FormBuilder, for example. Another example would be something like this:

```
$doctrine->getManager->getRepository('Software')->findAll();
```

Returns all of the extraneous entries the users don't want to see as well.

What I need to do is get Doctrine to run a query like `select * from only software`. I've attempted to do this through the `query_builder` option in the FormBuilder, but I could only find a way to return an array of the results I wanted - Not an instance of QueryBuilder like the FormBuilder requires.

My concern is that my only option here is to manually query for the software, then pass that into the form as an option. This isn't ideal, but it's starting to seem like the only option.. I'm just hoping someone out there knows how to tell a Doctrine entity not to inherit from other tables, essentially using the `only` statement in SQL.

I have no way to discriminate between `software` and `software_dynamic` through Doctrine; they're identical tables but one is manually populated from a CRUD (The ones the users want to see) and the other is populated automatically through an API (Only useful to the backend).

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information on how you configured these two entities to either help me or others help you solving this? :-)

Comment: Also did you define any fields in your form that could trigger Doctrine's lazy loading behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure any properties of the entity would be relevant here, but correct me if I'm wrong. What happened is I defined the entity's class and stated @ORM\Table(name="software"), and as a result, Doctrine always selects n from software. Because of this, the database appends any relevant results from software_dynamic as well; they are basically the same table if you query software. If I say @ORM\Table(name="only software"), it works for listing only software table rows, but breaks Doctrine otherwise.

Comment: I apologize that things aren't very clear. The issue's terminology kind of eludes me; I'm not totally sure how best to approach the problem. I've been going through Doctrine's source code and googling as much as I can think of, but I can tell I'm not fully understanding the issue and so asking how to solve it is really tricky!

Answer (score 0):

Have you **accidentally** set the fetch mode to EAGER loading? This would indeed cause the opposite effect of what you desire.

**However**, when you **do** require eager loading in some cases:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT e FROM MyProject\Entity e");
$query->setFetchMode("MyProject\AssociatedEntity", "field", "EAGER");
$query->execute();
```

Comment: That would be towards the inverse of what I want. I don't want eager loading of inherited or related entities; I want to select only from the parent table.

Comment: Realized the way I described things wasn't that clear as I thought it was, updated the post.